# jQuery validation plugin click checkbox to remove disable another checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Is there a way to remove checkbox disable from another checkbox disable? Below is my code:

```
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/dev/themes/base/ui.button.css" />
<script src="jquery-validation-1.8.1/lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-validation-1.8.1/lib/jquery.metadata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-validation-1.8.1/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen" />
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#platinum").click(function () {
                  $("#schedule").removeAttr("disabled")
                });
                });


                </script>
</head> 

        <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
        <h3>Booking Confirmation</h3>
        <div style="border: medium none;display: inline;padding: 0;text-align:left">
        <h4>I wish to participate in the JUMP START Vitality Challenge Program:</h4>
        <p><input id="platinum" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Platinum" name="program[]" validate="required:true,minlength:1,maxlength:1" />Platinum Level - $677 - 5 sessions per week</p>
        <p><input id="gold" type="checkbox" value="Gold" name="program[]" />Gold Level - $497 - 2 sessions per week</p>
        <p><input id="silver" type="checkbox" value="Silver" name="program[]" />Silver Level - $297</p>
        </div>
        <div style="border: medium none;display: inline;padding: 0;text-align:left">
        <h4>I wish to participate in the JUMP START Vitality Challenge Program, and I am a current Jump Start client:</h4>
        <p><input type="checkbox" value="Platinum - Current Client" name="program[]" />Platinum Level - $598 - 5 sessions per week</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" value="Gold - Current Client" name="program[]" />Gold Level - $418 - 2 sessions per week</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" value="Silver - Current Client" name="program[]" />Silver Level - $218</p>
        </div>
        <p><label class="error" for="program[]" >Please select one.</label></p>

        <div>
        <table>
        <tr><td><h3>Payment Options</h3></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <h4><input type="checkbox" value="Paypal" name="payment[]" validate="required:true,minlength:1,maxlength:1" />1. Credit Card or Paypal </h4>
                <iframe src="paypal.php" width="100%" height="100%" style="border:none">
                </iframe>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <br/>
                    <h4>2. Bank Transfer</h4>
                        <p><input type="checkbox" value="Bank Transfer" name="payment[]" />I am securing my place by sending in my completed forms and transferring the full amount to the Jump Start bank account. Please send an email with the receipt number once this is done.</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Bank: Westpac</li>
                        <li>Account Name: Jump Start Personal Training Pty Ltd</li>
                        <li>Account Number: 351 539</li>
                        <li>BSB: 032197</li>
                    </ul>
                    <br/>
                    <h4><input type="checkbox" value="Call the office" name="payment[]" />3. Call the office on (02) 9904 1201 with your credit card details for payment.</h4>
                    <p><label class="error" for="payment[]" >Please select one.</label></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>      
    <table cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0" width="657" style="padding:5px;border:solid 1px;" id="schedule">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><h3>Monday</h3></td>
            <td><h3>Tuesday</h3></td>
            <td><h3>Wednesday</h3></td>
            <td><h3>Thursday</h3></td>
            <td><h3>Friday</h3></td>
            <td><h3>Saturday</h3></td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Fitness Circuit 6.30-7.30am" disabled="disabled" /><p>Fitness Circuit<br/> <span>6.30-7.30am</span></p></td>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Fit 2 Box 6.30-7.30am" disabled="disabled"  /><p>Fit 2 Box<br/> <span>6.30-7.30am</span></p></td>
                <td><p align="CENTER">&nbsp;</p></td>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Fit 2 Box 6.30-7.30am" disabled="disabled"  /><p>Fit 2 Box<br/> <span>6.30-7.30am</span></p></td>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Fitness Circuit 6.30-7.30am" disabled="disabled"  /><p>Fitness Circuit<br/> <span>6.30-7.30am</span></p></td>
                <td><p align="CENTER">&nbsp;</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Run 4 Fun 6.30-7.30am" disabled="disabled"  /><p>Run 4 Fun<br/> <span>6.30-7.30am</span></p></td>
                <td><p>&nbsp;</span></p></td>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Fitness Circuit 7.30-8.30am" disabled="disabled"  /><p>Fitness Circuit<br/><span>7.30-8.30am</span></p></td>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Core Strength 7.15-8.15am" disabled="disabled"  /><p>Core Strength<br/> <span>7.15-8.15am</span></p></td>
                <td><p><span>&nbsp;</span></p></td>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Walk 2 Trot 8.30-9.15am" disabled="disabled" /><p>Walk 2 Trot<br/><span>8.30-9.15am</span></p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p><span>&nbsp;</span></p></td>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Fitness Circuit 9.30-10.30am*" /><p>Fitness Circuit<br/> <span>9.30-10.30am*</span></p></td>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Fitness Circuit 9.30-10.30am*" /><p>Fitness Circuit<br/> <span>9.30-10.30am*</span></p></td>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Fitness Circuit 9.30-10.30am*" /><p>Fitness Circuit<br/> <span>9.30-10.30am*</span></p></td>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Fitness Circuit 9.30-10.30am" /><p>Fitness Circuit<br/> <span>9.30-10.30am</span></p></td>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Core Strength 9.30-10.30am" /><p>Core Strength<br/><span>9.30-10.30am</span></p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p><span>&nbsp;</span></p></td>
                <td><p><span>&nbsp;</span></p></td>
                <td><p><span>&nbsp;</span></p></td>
                <td><p><span>&nbsp;</span></p></td>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Fitness Circuit 10.30-11.30am*" /><p>Fitness Circuit<br/><span>10.30-11.30am*</span></p></td>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Fitness Circuit 10.30-11.30am" /><p>Fitness Circuit<br/><span>10.30-11.30am</span></p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Fitness Circuit 6.30-7.30pm" /><p>Fitness Circuit<br/><span>6.30-7.30pm</span></p></td>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Fitness Circuit 6.30-7.30pm" /><p>Fitness Circuit<br/><span>6.30-7.30pm</span></p></td>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Fit 2 Box 6.30-7.30pm" /><p>Fit 2 Box<br/><span>6.30-7.30pm</span></p></td>
                <td><input name="schedule[]" id="schedule" type="checkbox" value="Fitness Circuit 6.30-7.30pm" /><p>Fitness Circuit<br/><span>6.30-7.30pm</span></p></td>
                <td><p><span>&nbsp;</span></p></td>
                <td><p><span>&nbsp;</span></p></td>
                <p><label class="error" for="schedule[]" >Please select your sessions.</label></p>


            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I want to remove disable from id #schedule checkbox when I click id #platinum checkbox...

Comment: Having multiple elements with the same `id` is not legal in HTML. You'll want to look those elements up by `class` or `name`

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to have multiple DOM elements with the same `id` in a document. You should make sure that `id` is unique on your page.

With that in mind, you could select the elements by `name[]` and disable them that way:

**jQuery < 1.6, 1.61**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#platinum").click(function() {
        $("input[name='schedule[]']").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
```

**jQuery >= 1.6**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#platinum").click(function() {
        $("input[name='schedule[]']").prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
```